# Patching together continuous maps from disjoint $G_\delta$ sets into a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, denote by $\tau_d$ the induced metric topology. Let $G_i$, $i\in I$, be a countable union of disjoint $G_\delta$-subsets. Mind that it could be that $G_i \notin \tau_d$ and $\cup_{i \in I}G_i$ could be a proper subset of $X$. Consider continuous maps $f_i:(G_i,d_{G_i}) \mapsto (Y,h)$, where $d_{G_i}$ is the restriction of $d$ to $G_i$ and $(G,h)$ is a metric space.

**Question** is it possible to patch together the maps $f_i$'s and extend the map so obtained, say $f$, to a continuous map $f:(X,d)\mapsto (Y,h)$?

**Remark 1** Assume that in particular $G_i$'s are open and cover $X$, i.e. $X=\cup_{i \in I}G_i$. Then the disjoint union topological space $\coprod_{i\in I}(G_I,d_{G_i})$ and $(X,d)$ should coincide (since each ${\tau_{d_{G_i}}}$ would consists of intersections between $G_i$ and open sets, say $U$, of $\tau_d$; but then also $G_i\cap U \in \tau_d$). Then $f=f'$ would exists by the universal property of coproducts.

**Remark 2** Let's now give up the assumption $X=\cup_{i \in I}G_i$, but retain $G_i \in \tau_d, \, \forall i \in I$. Endow $G=\cup_{i \in I}G_i$ with the restriction of $d$, say $d_G$. Then, we still have $G_i \in \tau_G$ and $f$ obtains as in the previous remark, but now as a continuous map from $(G,d_G)$ to $(Y,h)$. If $G$ is *dense* in $X$, then there exists also a continuous map $f'$ extending $f$ to $X$ (but it may not be unique, see e.g. the answer to this question [Extending a function by continuity from a dense subset of a space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76854/extending-a-function-by-continuity-from-a-dense-subset-of-a-space) ).

**Remark 3** Let's finally give up also the assumption $G_i \in \tau_d, \, \forall i \in I$. If there existed $\tau_d$-open, disjoint sets $G_i'$ such that $G_i=G \cap G_i'$, then the $G_i \in \tau_{d_G}$, then it should be possible to obtain $f:(G,d_G)\mapsto (Y,h)$ as above and, if $G$ is again dense, then we can extend $f$ to some continuous $f'$.

Does the third remark make sense? Is it always possible to construct the aforementioned open sets $G_i'$? (If yes, this is not immediately clear to me). Can we obtain a positive answer to the above main question also beyond the restrictions in Remark 3? (That was the more general setting I managed to handle so far). Any help or refs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal requirement is of course that $f_i\mid_{G_i \cap G_j} = f_j\mid_{G_i \cap G_j}$ for all $i, j$. So let us assume this in the sequel.

Remark 2: It is false. [Extending a function by continuity from a dense subset of a space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76854) deals only with extending *uniformly continuous* maps. Take for example $X = [0,1], G = (0,1]$ and $f : G \to \mathbb [0,1], f(x) = \sin(1/x)$. This has no continuous extension to $[0,1]$ since $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Remark 3: In that case the $G_i$ are open in $G$, thus you get $f : G \to H$ as desired. But there is no reason why an extension to $X$ should be possible.

Comment: Actually the answer to the linked question starts with ``If you only need continuity of $g$, then continuity (not uniform) of $f$ is enough", where in my case $g$ would be $f'$. Is the cited statement false? According to that answer, it would seem that uniformity is only needed for unicity. Or, more informally, if the extension is not univocally defined (for which uniform continuity is needed), is the extension substantially useless, since it is not well defined?

Comment: In addition, in Remark 2, estension of $f$ to some $f'$ should be allowed by adding assumptions on $(Y,h)$, e.g. Theorem 1 A. in blair (1976) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2040816?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: It is definitely wrong that any continuous $f : D \to Y$ defined on a dense subset of a metric space $X$ has a continuous extension $F : X \to Y$. See my example for Remark 2. If $X$ is compact and $Y$ is complete, then $F$ exists **iff** $f$ is  uniformly continuous. The acknowledged answer to the linked question does not define an extension $g$ of $f$, but only proves that the definition $g(x) = \lim_{x_n \to x, x_n \in D} f(x_n)$, **if** this limit always exists, yields a continuous $g$.See Srivatsan's answer to the question.

Comment: Uniform continuity is irrelevant for the uniqueness of continuous extensions. In fact, any two contiuous maps $F : F' : X \to Y$ into a  Hausdorff space $Y$ which agree on a dense subset $D$ agree on $\bar D = X$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305472

Comment: Blair's paper gives conditions on $Y$ **and** on $f$ which guarantee the existence of an extension. It does not say that any $f$ has an extension.

Comment: Sure. Anyway in Remark 2 at least a *continuous* map $f:(G,d_G)\mapsto (Y,h)$ obtains, right? So, if $G$ is dense **and** $(Y,h)$ is compact, the continuous extension to $X$ exists, correct?

Comment: Yes, $f : G \to Y$ exists. But see my example where we have a single $G_1 = (0,1]$ (i.e. $G = G_1$). $X = Y = [0,1]$ are compact, but $f$ does not have a continuous extension to $X$.

Comment: Ok, many thanks, I misinterpreted the reference by Blair.

Answer (score 2):

Every singleton set in $\mathbb R$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set. Consider the collection of sets $\{\{r\}: r \in \mathbb Q\}$. This is a disjoint countable collection of $G_{\delta}$ sets. Let $f$ be any map from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$. This gives a family of continuous functions on these singletons.  Your question asks if we can find a continuous map extending these functions. The answer is obviously NO.

Comment: Ok. But do you think that, at least in some cases, the sets $G_i'$ might exist and Remark 3 work well, or do you think it's incorrect?